# What is the most efficient way to make a notification system for saved searches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, notifications, postgis

I'm building an app that has a complex search (including geographic data), the users can save the searches so they can see it later, but also they can be notified if a new item is placed on the list.

When I think about this problem I see thousands of searches that I need to process in a background job every week (or day) and as each search is mostly unique, I can not process them in batches, meaning I need to make a full search on the database with all the items the user choose, I'm worried about the performance issues this can have in the application.

I was wondering if there is a pattern or a tool that can help me with this problem, or how is the best way I can take to solve it.

I'm using ruby on rails and PostgreSQL with Postgis on the stack.

Comment: I would look at the Elastic Search wrapper for ruby: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails.